# Why Django automatically adds slash after url that ends with ".htm" and doesn't when url ends with ".html"?

Tags: django

I have a problem that Django automatically adds slash to urls that ends with ".htm"

Url like:
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/link.htm`
becomes:
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/link.htm/`

But if I rename "link.htm" to "link.html" then no problem happens.

Where could be the issues?

Thanks.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from dtunes.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),

     url(r'^(?P<path>.*\.(htm|html|jpg|jpeg|css|gif|js|png))$', "django.views.static.serve", {
            "document_root": settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }, name="media"),

    url(r'^img/tr.gif', track, name='track'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^smscoin/ipn/', ipn, name='smscoin_ipn'),
    url(r'^download-link/', get_download_link, name='get_download_link'),
    url(r'^get/(?P<name>.*)/$', item_details, name="item_details"),
    url(r'^getnow', item_details_paid, name="item_details_paid"),
    url(r'^download/(?P<name>.*)/$', send_direct_file, name="send_direct_file"),
    url(r'^(?P<name>.*)/$', plain_page, name="plain_page"),       

)
```

Comment: How does the URL mapping looks like for this resource?

Comment: You may want to reconsider serving static media like that.  Django's static serve is not intended for any sort of production environment -- it's unstable, slow, and isn't secure.  The built-in django.views.static.serve is intended for development only; it doesn't look as though you've set it up to be able to easily switch to something else for production.

Comment: Sure it's used for development only. On production where I use Nginx for serving static files I don't have this problem. It happens in development environment and I can't find a reason :(
My Nginx production configuration firstly check if static file exists, if not - tries to serve using Django that is running as FCGI.

Answer (score 2):

[Django has a setting, "APPEND_SLASH"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash), which adds a slash to URLs that are not otherwise matched in the URLConf, but would be matched if a slash were added.  So you probably have some regex pattern in your urls.py that is matching ".htm/".

It looks like you are using Django to [serve static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)?  If so, you might make sure this is configured properly.  During development, to keep things DRY, I usually use the following in my "urls.py" file to serve static media.  This requires a properly configured [MEDIA_ROOT](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) and [MEDIA_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url) in settings.py:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns(
   ...
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^%s/(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:-1],
                'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```